# Is a question asking for examples acceptable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question was quickly closed and just as quickly reopened, with two sides both passionate about whether or not it is acceptable for SO.

[How can I use LINQ to avoid nested loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301904/request-for-an-example-of-using-linq-to-avoid-nested-loops)

Arguments in favor of closing centered around the notion that it is a "poll" question.

Arguments in favor of not closing (and reopening) centered around the idea that the question seeks specific answers to a fairly narrow question, though certainly the OP is looking for a range of example solutions rather than a specific "best" solution.

Is this question acceptable?  What concrete guidance indicates whether it is/isn't?

Comment: Personally, I'd be inclined to close it, as it's subjective as to whether a "best" answer could be chosen, which would be desirable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw the question and my instinct was 'poll', but I read the comments and decided to wait and see. I agreed with your comment that the questioner was asking for concrete examples, so I figured it's worth a shot to see what kind of answers the question garners.

My tendency was to agree with Anthony Pegram:

> This question is "create an arbitrary problem and then a solution
>   where Linq is useful." This is not an effective SO question. We
>   provide solutions to problems, not ideas for problems that then need a
>   solution. This is a poll, not a question with a single best answer.

However, having read the answers I don't believe that this is a constructive question. Asking for 'examples' of something leads to both duplicate answers (the obvious `SelectMany`) and incorrect answers (i.e. offtopic, e.g. the `GroupBy` answer which the questioner notes he already grasps).

The question is too close to being a simple *What's good about LINQ?* type poll question. I don't understand whether it's serious or just an attempt at making a popular question.

> people say you can avoid heavy nested loops by using LINQ, but few LINQ examples come with pre-linq code listings

If the questioner had googled, there are plenty of examples of 'pre-linq code'.

These two, for example, deal with **actual** problems.

- [Converting nested foreach loops to LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666138/converting-nested-foreach-loops-to-linq)
- [How to rewrite this foreach looping using linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947693/how-to-rewrite-this-foreach-looping-using-linq)

If the questioner had an actual problem then they should ask that question. As it stands, it's just an attempt at starting a discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I think your reasoning is dead on.

> His wording is a little loose, but at the core he's asking "how can I use Linq to avoid heavily nested loops." Seems specific enough to allow for specific, useful answers... which he got.

Edit the question a little (specifically the title and the last sentence) to avoid the bad impression and I think it would be perfect.  Something like:

> ## How can I use LINQ to avoid nested loops?
>
> I have an OK understanding of the LINQ operators and the syntax choices. Problem is, people say you can avoid heavy nested loops by using LINQ, but we usually need a foreach or two to iterate the query anyway.
>
> <would have been good to have an unoptimized example here in the original>
>
> How can I use LINQ to avoid these nested loops?

He can get a real answer, hopefully one that's thorough, and use that to make his own examples.  The fact that he needs examples for a presentation isn't relevant.